# Adding multiple check boxes from the db in php does not show up

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following  code that I would like to use to add check boxes to the interface depending on the selected  drop down value

```
    <!--drop down list for the floors--> 
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ddlFloorNo"><?php echo $_data['add_new_form_field_text_10']; ?> :</label>
    <select onchange="getUnitReport(this.value)" name="ddlFloorNo" id="ddlFloorNo" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--<?php echo $_data['add_new_form_field_text_11']; ?>--</option>
        <?php
        $result_floor = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tbl_add_floor order by fid ASC");
        while ($row_floor = mysqli_fetch_array($result_floor)) {
            ?>
            <option <?php
            if ($floor_id == $row_floor['fid']) {
                echo 'selected';
            }
            ?> value="<?php echo $row_floor['fid']; ?>">
                <?php echo $row_floor['floor_no']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
 <!--Check boxes to be displayed based on the selected floor inn the drop down list above--> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ChkOwnerUnit"><?php echo $_data['add_new_form_field_text_8']; ?> : </label>
        <?php
        $result_unit = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tbl_add_unit where floor_no ='" . (int) $row_floor['fid'] . "' order by uid ASC");
        while ($row_unit = mysqli_fetch_array($result_unit)) {
            ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="ChkOwnerUnit[]" value="<?php echo $row_unit['uid']; ?>"/>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

My  problem is that  the checkboxes do not show up.
What could I be doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure there is data in that table with a `floor_no` matching the `fid` you are passing

Comment: How exactly did you determine that they don't show up? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Did you check the `page source` using your browser to see if there is anything there, but it is just not showing up due to some HTML issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes there is data

Comment: @NicoHaase they are not visible

Comment: This was working  when I was using option select instead of checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are not getting data in your line

```
$result_unit = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tbl_add_unit where floor_no ='" . (int) $row_floor['fid'] . "' order by uid ASC");
```

**$row_floor** is not accessible at there. You need to make changes in either html or create array to store ids.

Comment: I did the same thing with option select but it worked would you give me a clue on how to go about making it work? I am new with php

Comment: you are trying to use that `$row_floor` variable out of the `while` loop so, you do not have data in `(int) $row_floor['fid']`, thus query will not return any thing  and checkboxes are not showing

Comment: the $row_floor is in the dropdown menu

Comment: yes and you are using the ids `(int) $row_floor['fid']` from that variable for getting checkbox values, but these ids are not accessible there in another query. Please create an array to store the ids and use that array.  

if that is dependent data then you should go for `AJAX` call

Comment: Would you proovide me with a link to some tutorial on the ajax?

Comment: AJAX alone won't solve the problem, and there are tons of tutorials around